# SCRIPT5007 Javascript error in IE9 and lower

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I have got this problem that is driving me crazy. I have made this Javascript function that is working in every browser and only in IE9 and lower I get this error.

This is the error I got in dutch.

***SCRIPT5007: Kan de eigenschap value van een niet-gedefinieerde verwijzing of een verwijzing naar een lege waarde niet instellen***

This is the translated version:

***SCRIPT5007: Can the value property of an undefined reference or a reference to an empty value not set.***

This is my Javascript function:

```
        function Calculate()
    {
        var l = document.getElementById('aantal-caps').value;
        var l2 = document.getElementById('aantal-paraplu').value;
        var l3 = document.getElementById('aantal-blue-tooth').value;
        var l4 = document.getElementById('aantal-backpack').value;
        var result = l * 12 + l2 * 12 + l3 * 20 + l4 * 50;
        document.getElementById('totaal').innerHTML = result;
        document.aanvraag.totaal.value = result; 
        var punten = 345; // Aantal spaarpunten van de klant. Die kan jij hier inschieten.
        var bereken = punten - result;
        if(bereken < 0)
            {
                bereken = '<span style="color:#ff0000"><b>Saldo niet toereikend</b></span>';
                document.getElementById("Submitform").disabled = true; 
            } else 
            {
                bereken = punten - result;
                document.getElementById("Submitform").disabled = false; 
            }
        document.getElementById('punten-aantal').innerHTML = bereken;
        document.getElementById('uwpunten').innerHTML = punten;

    }
    window.onload=Calculate;
```

This is my HTML table where I show the selected javascript values:

```
<table style="float:left; width:350px; height:247px;">
<tr>
    <th height="15px">Spaarpunten</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Uw aantal spaarpunten : </td>
    <td><strong style="font-size:14px"><span id="uwpunten" style="color:#0acb00;">0<input type="hidden" name="uwpunten" id="uwpunten" value="" /></span></strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>De huidige selectie kost u : </td>
    <td><strong style="font-size:14px"><span id="totaal" style="color:#F00;">0<input type="hidden" name="totaal" id="totaal" value="" /></span></strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>-------------------------------</td>
    <td>-----</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>U heeft nog : </td>
    <td><strong style="font-size:14px"><span id="punten-aantal" style="color:#0acb00;">0<input type="hidden" name="punten-aantal" id="punten-aantal" value="" /></span></strong></td>
</tr>
```

This is my selection form:

```
    <table width="700" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" style="float:left;">
    <tr>
        <th>Kies een product</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="cap.jpg" /></td>
        <td><img src="paraplu.jpg" /></td>
        <td><img src="bandenspeaker.jpg" /></td>
        <td><img src="backpack.jpg" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><select id="aantal-caps" name="aantal-caps" onChange="Calculate();">
                <option value="0" selected="selected">Kies het aantal</option>
                <option value="1" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-caps']) == "1") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>1</option>
                <option value="2" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-caps']) == "2") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>2</option>
                <option value="3" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-caps']) == "3") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>3</option>
                <option value="4" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-caps']) == "4") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>4</option>
                <option value="5" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-caps']) == "5") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>5</option>
                <option value="6" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-caps']) == "6") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>6</option>
                <option value="7" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-caps']) == "7") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>7</option>
                <option value="8" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-caps']) == "8") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>8</option>
                <option value="9" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-caps']) == "9") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>9</option>
                <option value="10" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-caps']) == "10") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>10</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><select id="aantal-paraplu" name="aantal-paraplu" onChange="Calculate();">
                <option value="0" selected="selected">Kies het aantal</option>
                <option value="1" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-paraplu']) == "1") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>1</option>
                <option value="2" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-paraplu']) == "2") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>2</option>
                <option value="3" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-paraplu']) == "3") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>3</option>
                <option value="4" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-paraplu']) == "4") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>4</option>
                <option value="5" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-paraplu']) == "5") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>5</option>
                <option value="6" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-paraplu']) == "6") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>6</option>
                <option value="7" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-paraplu']) == "7") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>7</option>
                <option value="8" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-paraplu']) == "8") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>8</option>
                <option value="9" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-paraplu']) == "9") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>9</option>
                <option value="10" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-paraplu']) == "10") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>10</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><select id="aantal-blue-tooth" name="aantal-blue-tooth" onChange="Calculate();">
                <option value="0" selected="selected">Kies het aantal</option>
                <option value="1" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-blue-tooth']) == "1") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>1</option>
                <option value="2" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-blue-tooth']) == "2") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>2</option>
                <option value="3" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-blue-tooth']) == "3") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>3</option>
                <option value="4" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-blue-tooth']) == "4") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>4</option>
                <option value="5" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-blue-tooth']) == "5") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>5</option>
                <option value="6" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-blue-tooth']) == "6") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>6</option>
                <option value="7" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-blue-tooth']) == "7") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>7</option>
                <option value="8" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-blue-tooth']) == "8") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>8</option>
                <option value="9" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-blue-tooth']) == "9") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>9</option>
                <option value="10" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-blue-tooth']) == "10") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>10</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><select id="aantal-backpack" name="aantal-backpack" onChange="Calculate();">
                <option value="0" selected="selected">Kies het aantal</option>
                <option value="1" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-backpack']) == "1") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>1</option>
                <option value="2" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-backpack']) == "2") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>2</option>
                <option value="3" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-backpack']) == "3") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>3</option>
                <option value="4" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-backpack']) == "4") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>4</option>
                <option value="5" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-backpack']) == "5") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>5</option>
                <option value="6" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-backpack']) == "6") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>6</option>
                <option value="7" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-backpack']) == "7") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>7</option>
                <option value="8" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-backpack']) == "8") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>8</option>
                <option value="9" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-backpack']) == "9") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>9</option>
                <option value="10" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-backpack']) == "10") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>10</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Sorry for posting all the code but most of the time it is better to understand what I'm doing.

This field:

```
<td><strong style="font-size:14px"><span id="totaal" style="color:#F00;">0<input type="hidden" name="totaal" id="totaal" value="" /></span></strong></td>
```

is the only field that is working. Other two fields I get SCRIPT5007 ERROR on page load and when I select another field in my form.

Why is this only happening in IE9 and lower? And is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: If it's a browser error, show the **rendered** HTML, not the source mark-up.  And if you can tell us which line of code the error is from, that would be useful (IE normally gives you a file and line number)

Comment: Thanks for putting me in the right direction!:) This line was causing the error: document.aanvraag.totaal.value = result;

Comment: Actually the SCRIPT5007 error text in english is: "Unable to get value of the property variable_name: object is null or undefined."

Answer (score -1):

```
document.aanvraag.totaal.value = result;
```

That was causing my error

Comment: Please explain why this is the fix of the problem, so that it might help any future users who see this question/answer.

Comment: I found that errors like [SCRIPT50xx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn423949(v=vs.85).aspx) are |Script error codes (dah). After further investigation there I found the error [5007 as Run-time error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1dk3k160(v=vs.94).aspx) that says: **Object Expected** You attempted to invoke the Object.prototype.toString or Object.prototype.valueOf method on an object of a type other than Object. The object of this type of invocation must be of type Object.